# Quickly returning all numbers less than or divisible by Seven

Tags: c#

So i had an interview question: Write a function that takes a number and returns all numbers less than or divisible by 7

```
    private List<int> GetLessThanOrDivisbleBySeven(int num)
    {
       List<int> ReturnList = new List<int>();

       for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
       {
           if(i <7 || i % 7 == 0)
           {
              ReturnList.Add(i);
            }
         }

         return ReturnList;
      }
```

So far so good. The follow up question was: Let's say that call was being made 10s of thousands of times an hour. How could you speed it up?

I said if you knew what your queue was you could break up your queue and thread it. That got me some points i feel. However, he wanted to know if there was anything in the function i could do.

I came up with the idea to test if the num was greater than 7. if so initialize the list with 1 - 7 and start the loop int i = 8 which i think was ok but is there another way i am missing?

Comment: Always 7? Cache the list.

Comment: Are you trying to find values or indexes that are "under/divisible by 7"? The question makes it seem like they want values, but your example returns indexes.

Comment: i would be the value. num is the number. i is all numbers less then or equal to the number you send

Comment: Are you sure the question wasn't simply: return all numbers that are less than `num` that are divisible by `7`?

Comment: That...doesn't make a lot of sense, actually.

Comment: im sure. Dont ask me about the questions usefulness. i just had to answer lol

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question, okay.

Comment: hahaha true that - anyway, i'd cache the return values in some fashion. Personally, I'd have asked for clarification, because you can cache by parameters easily for like a web method or whatever then you don't have to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Oh, @Muckeypuck, this is actually not a great question for here because it's a discussion point. No "right" answer. I didn't downvote it, but that might be why it was

Comment: Well there is definitely a right way to speed it up yea? i mean its alot more concrete than "whats better c# or vb?" not arguing, just wondering how that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to speed it up without caching, you can just increment i by 7 to get all numbers divisible by 7, it will be something like this:

```
        static private List<int> GetLessThanOrDivisbleBySeven(int num) {
            List<int> ReturnList;
            int i;
            if (num <= 7) {
                ReturnList = new List<int>();
                for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
                    ReturnList.Add(i);
                }
                return ReturnList;
            }

            ReturnList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            i = 7;
            while (i <= num) {
                ReturnList.Add(i);
                i += 7;
            }

            return ReturnList;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the results. Each time your function is being called, check what numbers are in the cache, and calculate the rest.

If the current number is smaller, return the appropriate cached results.

Comment: And what would your cache lookup look like?  I bet the cache lookup would be more expensive than recalculating.

Comment: A hashmap lookup is far faster than a loop calc, i believe

Comment: i like this idea but it could be expensive memory wise

Answer (score 1):

use the previous results when calculating new list

```
int oldMax = 0;
List<int> ReturnList = new List<int>();

private List<int> GetLessThanOrDivisbleBySeven(int num)
{
       if (num > oldMax )
       {
           oldMax  = num;
           for(int i = oldMax ; i <= num; i++)
           {
              if(i <7 || i % 7 == 0)
              {
                 ReturnList.Add(i);
               }
            }
              return ReturnList;
       }
       else 
       {
            // create a copy of ReturnList  and Remove from  the copy numbers bigger than num
       }
}
```

Comment: this is a good idea but what if the numbers sent were 7 25 6?

there was no guarantee the numbers were incrementally higher than the last

Comment: right that is why there the else condition that deals with numbers smaller the largest number so far

Comment: oh i see you addressed that. hmm maybe

Comment: i guess this would depend on the removal cost.

Answer (score 0):

Interview questions are usually more about how you approach problems in general and not so much the technical implementation. In your case you could do a lot of small things, like caching the list outside. Caching different versions of the list in a dictionary, if space was not a problem. Maybe somebody can come up with some smarter math, to save on calculations, but usually it's more about asking the right questions and considering the right options. Say, if you ask "does this program run on a web server? maybe I can store all data in a table and use it as a quick lookup instead of recalculating every time." There might not even be a correct or best answer, they probably just want to hear, that you can think of special situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the numbers that are divisible by 7 and smaller than num by calculating res = num/7 and then create a loop from 1 to res and multiply each number by 7.

```
private List<int> GetLessThanOrDivisbleBySeven(int num)
{
   List<int> ReturnList = new List<int>();
   // Add all the numbers that are less than 7 first
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
      ReturnList.Add(i);

   int res = num / 7;// num = res*7+rem
   for(i = 1; i <= res; i++)
   {
       ReturnList.Add(i*7);
   }

   return ReturnList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about memory management and how the `List` class works.

Unless you tell it the capacity it will need, it allocates a new array whenever it runs out of space, however it is easy to work out the size it will need to be.

Returning an array would save one object allocation compared to using a `List`, so discuss the tradeoff between the two.

What about using "yeild return" to advoid allocating memory, or does it have other costs to consider?

Is the same number requested often, if so consider cacheing.

Would LINQ, maybe using `Enumerable.Range` help?

An experienced C# programmer would be expected to know at least a little about all the above and that memory management is often an hidden issue.